# What does 'abstract' mean in a patent?

Tags: abstract

Looking through Google patents and on certain patents above the description is says 'ABSTRACT'. I am new to the patent world, still learning.

Comment: It's a summary https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_(summary)

Answer (score 1):

Almost all literary works have abstract, brief, introduction, synopsis including but not limited to overview. Meaning anything that is most relevant to the complete subject may have any of those elements. It would help prospects or readers what to expect as well serve as a teaser or an appetite to make them want or be curious and interested to dig in the content. For patent it will guide the evaluator what to expect from the entirety of the application.

Answer (score 0):

It's a short summary of the invention.

Here is a link with more detail from Cornell: https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/37/1.72

Advice I was given on the Abstract by patent attorneys was to read the abstracts of patents in similar fields to get a sense of what people include and exclude.  ([Google Patents](https://patents.google.com/) is a great place to do this.)

Answer (score 0):

Abstract is the summary of our work. Usually ends with one paragraph and will be added in the starting. Below the title.